# Function not defined when Importing Maya Python Script

Tags: python, function, import, maya

I have a tool I wrote in python that works completely fine when running in the maya script editor. However, I want to be able to import the script from the script directory. Which should be simple, and I am shocked I can't find the solution while searching the web.

My script format is like this example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# GUI code with buttons, they call the functions below.
#
#
def function1():
    #commands that do things

def function2():
    #commands that do things

#List of functions continues
```

Like I said, the program functions perfectly when run in the script editor. When saving the script to the directory and using this method:

```
import module 
reload (module)
module.function()
```

The GUI loads fine, but then when pushing the gui buttons, it says the functions are not defined. I don't understand what I am missing? If the script was loaded, shouldn't the functions be defined? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's your real code?

Comment: As written, you're calling `function()` rather than `function1()` or `function2()`

Answer (score 0):

Just because the GUI loads doesn't mean that all of your functions loaded properly. You need to put your file, (module.py) in a directory that is visible to your `PYTHONPATH`. If you're in Maya, you can also put it in the `MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH`

The `PYTHONPATH` / `MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH` are environment variables that you set before launching Maya. In a default Maya installation, some places where you could put your module.py file would be:

> (Windows) C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\Documents\maya\scripts
>
> (Linux) ~/maya/scripts
>
> (Mac) - Not sure, put probably also ~/maya/scripts

If you want to know where else you can place it, you run this

```
import os
print(os.getenv('MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH', ''))
print(os.getenv('PYTHONPATH', ''))
```

Any location in that list that you have write permissions to is OK to add your module.py file.

Also, it's worth noting that in your example module.function() would fail. It'd need to be module.function1() or module.function2() but I assume you know that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sup guys
So i know this is an old question that has already been answered but I have some extra information that helps in regards to GUI functions not working. (same error)
and there's basically nothing on this anywhere.

so the script director only helps when loading in the module through the shelf but will still return the same error "fuction is not defined"

this has todo with how the function is called through the UI element.
example.
this is will allow you to call function in the script editor
but gives you the function not defined error when the module is imported

```
def GUI_function():
  pm.button( command = "function()")

def function():
  do stuff
```

this on the other hand works.

```
def GUI_function():
  pm.button( command = function)

def function(*_):
  do stuff
```

i don't know why but maya tends to think function() is a nodetype
so remove the brackets if you not using arguments and you good to go